# How can I force number of items per row

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view, I'd like to render the following layout

[image: layout]

I tried to restrict the number of cells but I am unsure how to force the different count per row as you can see in the design

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private(set) lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    return collectionView
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1215686275, green: 0.1294117647, blue: 0.1490196078, alpha: 1)
    collectionView.contentInset = .init(top: 24, left: 24, bottom: 24, right: 24)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
  }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (5 * 5) + 6
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1647058824, green: 0.1764705882, blue: 0.2117647059, alpha: 1)
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.width / 2
    return cell
  }
}
```

My attempt only renders

[image]

The colors aren't important only the layout.

Comment: The code you have is fine.. although you will need to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and pass that subclass into UICollectionView initialization.  Your logic on how the layout is shaped will be within that subclass.  Have to ask the simple question though.. Can you just show/hide whatever is in the 1st and Xth cells?

Comment: Thanks Derek, how can I calculate the cells to hide? On a large screen the 7th cell may not be in the position as a smaller screen, so I would be hiding the wrong cell

Comment: You'd need to know the cell sizes, the padding, and the screen sizes to know which cell is the top left and top right most.  Same for the bottom row as well.

Comment: If you are iOS 13 and later, this is trivial using a compositional layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define the height / width for your collection view you can calculate the position

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private(set) lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    return collectionView
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1215686275, green: 0.1294117647, blue: 0.1490196078, alpha: 1)
    collectionView.contentInset = .init(top: 24, left: 24, bottom: 24, right: 24)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 340),
      collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
      collectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
      collectionView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    ])
  }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 48
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)

    switch indexPath.item {
      case 0, 5, 42, 47: cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1215686275, green: 0.1294117647, blue: 0.1490196078, alpha: 1)
      default: cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1647058824, green: 0.1764705882, blue: 0.2117647059, alpha: 1)
    }
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.width / 2
    return cell
  }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return .init(width: 28, height: 28)
  }
}
```